# Angular 8 make multiple http requests and combine all results

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to use forkJoin to perform multiple http get requests and then combine all results into a simple Array using Angular 8.

The problem is that I end up with an Array of Arrays... instead of one Array of strings

My code below. All endpoints return a list of strings.

```
autoCompleteValues: any;

ngOnInit() {

    let res1 = this.dataMessageService.getFoo1();
    let res2 = this.dataMessageService.getFoo2();
    let res3 = this.dataMessageService.getFoo3();
    let res4 = this.dataMessageService.getFoo4();
    let res5 = this.dataMessageService.getFoo5();

    forkJoin([res1, res2, res3, res4, res5]).subscribe(data => {

      this.autoCompleteValues = data;
      console.log(this.autoCompleteValues);
    });
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I combine all the results into one large Array?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

your code is correct since that is the expected behavior of forkjoin
you just need to map it a little bit

```
forkJoin([res1, res2, res3, res4, res5])
.pipe(map(data => data.reduce((result,arr)=>[...result,...arr],[])))
.subscribe(data =>{

  this.autoCompleteValues = data;
  console.log(this.autoCompleteValues);
});
```

Comment: when I use .map() i get the erorr "Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]>"

Comment: Working Demo of it : https://stackblitz.com/edit/fork-join-example-angular-5-6-7-ub72e9?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: this is indeed working! Would you edit your answer to include the stackblitz in your original answer please? So it could be easier for people to find in the future.

Comment: @khansen I didn't post any answer, just the stackbiltz link in the comment

Answer (score 9):

Instead of this:

```
forkJoin([res1, res2]).subscribe((data) => {
    console.log(data)
});
```

Do this:

```
forkJoin([res1, res2]).subscribe(([data1, data2]) => {
    console.log(data1)
    console.log(data2)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs/observable/forkJoin';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  response = [];
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    const request1 = this.http.get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/name/india');
    const request2 = this.http.get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/name/us');
    const request3 = this.http.get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/name/ame');
    const request4 = this.http.get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/name/ja');

    const requestArray = [];
    requestArray.push(request1);
    requestArray.push(request2);
    requestArray.push(request3);
    requestArray.push(request4);

    forkJoin(requestArray).subscribe(results => {
      console.log(results);
      this.response = results;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Will that load the data before the view of the component?  Sorta looks like it wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
 forkJoin([res1, res2, res3, res4, res5])
.pipe(map([res1, res2, res3, res4, res5]) 
    => [...res1, ...res2, ...res3, ...res4, ...res5])).subscribe(data => {
    this.autoCompleteValues = data;
    console.log(this.autoCompleteValues);
});
```

Make sure to import map operator too

```
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
```

Comment: I get an error Argument of type 'Observable<Object>[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object], index: number) => unknown'.
  Type 'Observable<Object>[]' provides no match for the signature '(value: [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object], index: number): unknown'

Answer (score 0):

If any of the inner observables supplied to forkJoin error you will lose the value of any other observables that would or have already completed.

Please refer below link:-
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

Comment: they all return results

Comment: After getting Result Loop for each Result return from different responses and push required unique the result into NEW Array.